# Sql Database connection with UWP

Tags: c#, sql, database, azure, uwp

I want to connect my app with the database. I created the database by using the Mobile Service on Azure and created with doing Add-Migration, etc. I can see my table on the left side of the visual studio and I populated the cells with information so it can show something on my app. My question is how can I show the data of the table to my app?

This is what I am thinking but It doesn't work.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     //var JsonResponse = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:58975/");
     //var partnerResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Partners>>(JsonResponse);
     //PartnersList.ItemsSource = partnerResult;

     MobileServiceCollection<Partners, Partners> items = await partnersTable
                .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Name != null)
                .ToCollectionAsync();

     IEnumerable itemsControl = items;

     PartnersList.ItemsSource = items; 

}
```

I commented out one try that didn't work and the rest of the code is another try that doesn't work.

This is the error I get:

An exception of type

> 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

`PartnerLst` is my `listbox` that will display everything.

I am new to databases so If you can guide me it would be awesome

Comment: Please specify what packages have you installed from NuGet. Do you test it on machine or in emulator? There is not enough code. Please add more

Comment: I noticed that you "created with doing Add-Migration", have you check the latest version after add migration? Have you update your database? I found not problem in your code. You may refer to [Data Points : A Code First Migrations Mystery: Solved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818489.aspx).